# How to find with javascript if element exists in DOM or it's virtual (has been just created by createElement)

Tags: javascript, virtual, document, element, exists

I'm looking for a way to find if element referenced in javascript has been inserted in the document.

Lets illustrate a case with following code:

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');

// Element has not been inserted in the document, i.e. not present

document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(elem);

// Element can now be found in the DOM tree
```

Jquery has :visible selector, but it won't give accurate result when I need to find that invisible element has been placed somewhere in the document.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's an easier method that uses the standard [Node.contains DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains) to check in an element is currently in the DOM:

```
document.body.contains(MY_ElEMENT);
```

*CROSS-BROWSER NOTE*: the document object in IE does not have a `contains()` method - to ensure cross-browser compatibility, use `document.body.contains()` instead. (or document.head.contains if you're checking for elements like link, script, etc)

---

**Notes on using a specific `document` reference vs Node-level `ownerDocument`:**

Someone raised the idea of using `MY_ELEMENT.ownerDocument.contains(MY_ELEMENT)` to check for a node's presence in the document. While this *can* produce the intended result (albeit, with more verbosity than necessary in 99% of cases), it can also lead to unexpected results, depending on use-case. Let's talk about why:

If you are dealing with a node that currently resides in an separate document, like one generated with `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()`, an `<iframe>` document, or an HTML Import document, and use the node's `ownerDocument` property to check for presence in what you *think* will be your main, visually rendered `document`, you will be in a world of hurt.

The node property `ownerDocument` is simply a pointer to *whatever* current document the node resides in. Almost every use-case of `contains` involves checking a *specific* `document` for a node's presence. You have 0 guarantee that `ownerDocument` is the same document you want to check - only you know that. The danger of `ownerDocument` is that someone may introduce any number of ways to reference, import, or generate nodes that reside in other documents. If they do so, and you have written your code to rely on `ownerDocument`'s relative inference, your code may break. To ensure your code always produces expected results, you should only compare against the *specifically referenced* `document` you intend to check, not trust relative inferences like `ownerDocument`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66649/discussion-on-answer-by-csuwldcat-how-to-find-with-javascript-if-element-exists).

Answer (score 14):

Do this:

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.setAttribute('id', 'my_new_div');

if (document.getElementById('my_new_div')) { } //element exists in the document.
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I had this on mind but was confused by possibility of having ids collision. Minute ago I developed new method by checking the element's parent var. It's not definitely new and i'm quite surprised that i haven't figured it before.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to test directly whether the element is contained in the document:

```
function isInDocument(el) {
    var html = document.body.parentNode;
    while (el) {
        if (el === html) {
            return true;
        }
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}

var elem = document.createElement('div');
alert(isInDocument(elem));
document.body.appendChild(elem);
alert(isInDocument(elem));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`jQuery.contains`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/):

```
jQuery.contains( document, YOUR_ELEMENT)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [compareDocumentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.compareDocumentPosition) to see if the element is contained inside `document`. [PPK](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#miscellaneous) has browser compatibility details and [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/comparing-document-position/) has a version for IE.

Comment: I had wondered about using `compareDocumentPosition` too, but the messing around to get it working in all browsers doesn't really seem worth it when you can do domething as simple as walking up the node tree, as in my answer, which will work in pretty much every browser.

Answer (score -1):

```
function isInDocument(query){
  return document.querySelectorAll(query).length != 0;
}
// isInDocument("#elemid")
```

Comment: This question was answered 7 years ago. Maybe you want to elaborate on how your answer is more accurate today than when it was originally answered? Don't just post some code without details, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.