# Can I know if element is in document or not?

Tags: javascript

```
var myElement = document.querySelector('div.example');// <div..></div>
/*
 * A lot time after, codes executed, whatever
 */
if( myElement.isInDocument )
{
     // Do something
}
```

Is there a easy way to know if 'myElement' still in document?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find with javascript if element exists in DOM or it's virtual (has been just created by createElement)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719002/how-to-find-with-javascript-if-element-exists-in-dom-or-its-virtual-has-been-j)

Comment: I've seen this question a few times, I'm not sure I linked to the best one.

Comment: @dystroy time after time we should made some questioning again, for example, now, contains() appears to be a good way to go.

Comment: Yes but 1) it was already in the question I linked to. 2) It's a frequent question, I'm sure there are other more recent identical questions. 3) You did zero research : google easily gives you the answer.

Comment: @dystroy 1) didn't, the answer presented here (as best soluctions) is not in the link you put, the closer answer is wrong answer (if you test, you'll see), 2) I can't argue if that, you live here, I'm not. 3) I tried 'element is in document javascript' and similar searchs.

Comment: I agree with you that the questions are similiar, BUT the title is a complete miss leading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains):

```
function isInPage(node) {
  return (node === document.body) ? false : document.body.contains(node);
}
```

Comment: ... Where has this function been my whole life?

Comment: @Kolink It wasn't in FF until relatively recently.

Comment: And yet IE5 had it XD Ah well, Firefox has been behind the curve for a good couple of years now.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this answer appears to be faster in my tests http://jsfiddle.net/Whuu7/. @Kolink is good too if I want support old Firefox which is not the case.

Comment: `node.contains(otherNode)` has worked on Firefox since December 2011 for anyone wondering.

Answer (score 6):

Since every element in the document is a child of the document, check to see if your element is:

```
function isInDocument(e) {
    while( e.parentNode) e = e.parentNode;
    return e === document;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains)

```
var myElement = document.querySelector('div.example');
console.log("elment ", myElement);
console.log("contains before ", document.body.contains(myElement));
myElement.parentNode.removeChild(myElement);
console.log("contains after ", document.body.contains(myElement));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vM86q/)

Answer (score 1):

You can first see if the `.contains()` method exists and use it if available.  If not, walk the parent chain looking for the document object.  From a prior project using code like this, you can't just rely on parentNode being empty (in some versions of IE) when you get to document so you have to also explicitly check for document like this:

```
function isInDocument(e) {
    if (document.contains) {
        return document.contains(e);
    } else {
        while (e.parentNode && e !== document) {
            e = e.parentNode;
        }
        return e === document;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For modern browsers the answer is `myElement.isConnected`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected