# In JavaScript how to check html element existing or not?

Tags: javascript, element, exists

I want to check whether a html element exists in the page.

```
var e = document.getElementById("test-node");
if(e == null)
{
 // do something
}
```

But the above code is not working. How can I check this element is existing or not? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: It should work. Can you make a fiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: You can do it very simple by using jQuery, is this library an option in you project?

Comment: use the entire jquery just for this test? LMAO

Comment: @Barmar : This element is a dropdown box. It has weveral options to select. Only for the existing users will be able to see the dropdown box. For new users, they cannot see it. When the user logged in I want to do some settings according to this option selected. For new users also I need to do some settings. To identify the new user I'm using this dropdown box's existence.

Comment: How are you preventing new users from seeing it? If you're just hiding it with CSS, the element still exists.

Comment: No it's not hiding through CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find with javascript if element exists in DOM or it's virtual (has been just created by createElement)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719002/how-to-find-with-javascript-if-element-exists-in-dom-or-its-virtual-has-been-j)

Comment: @Hello-World : May be a duplicate. Those answers didn't work for my issue. That's why I put this question.

Comment: You've just got the `if` condition backwards. Change `e == null` to `e !== null` and it'll work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will work:

```
if (document.getElementById("test-node")) {

   // exists

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can check it directly inside if condition.

try this code

```
if(document.getElementById("test-node"))
{
  // exists
}
else
{
//doesnot exists
}
```

fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/codingsolver/rPHTb/

Comment: It returns `null`, not `undefined`.

Comment: not working? look at this fiddler. it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/codingsolver/rPHTb/

Comment: @Su123. No prob. thanks for +1. and u r welcome. happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using the Node.contains DOM API, you can check for the presence of any element in the page (currently in the DOM) quite easily:

```
document.contains(someReferenceToADomElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var e = document.getElementById("test-node");
if(e)
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Same issue. If the element doesn't exist it should go to else part right? But it's not going to both

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
if (the_object.hasOwnProperty("ElementName"))  
  {  
   //some action

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var e = document.getElementById('test');
if(e){
    alert("we have the test div");
} else {
    alert("we don't have the test div");
}

var e2 = document.getElementById('test2');
if(e2){
    alert("we have the test2 div");
} else {
    alert("we don't have the test2 div");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7tgvb/1/

Comment: strange that, works for me. Fez Vrasta's solution also should work