# How to check if an element exists in DOM or not in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I removed an element from DOM with this code :

```
box1.parentNode.removeChild(box1);
```

How can I check if `box1` is in the DOM or not.

I want this because if I'll try to remove it from the DOM again, this will cause an error.

Comment: could you please make your question more clear? (i was not downvoting)

Comment: Why downvoting? His questions looks clear to me even the English if the english is not great. `if (box1) { box1.parentNode.removeChild(box1); }` ?

Comment: Can you provide proper details?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find with javascript if element exists in DOM or it's virtual (has been just created by createElement)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719002/how-to-find-with-javascript-if-element-exists-in-dom-or-its-virtual-has-been-j)

Comment: Down voting because OP  ***haven't tried Googling.***

Comment: upvoting because google kept sending me to an unrelated question with similar wording https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384286/how-do-you-check-if-a-javascript-object-is-a-dom-object

Answer (score 4):

> The Node.contains() method returns a Boolean value indicating whether a node is a descendant of a given node or not.

You can use **[Contain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)** :

```
if( node.contains( otherNode ) ){
    //Your code here
}
```

**NOTE :** To check in all the DOM use `document.contains(node)`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the `parentNode` property to see if the node is attached.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(div.parentNode !== null); //Attached, true
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
console.log(div.parentNode !== null); //Not attached, false
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1") // EXAMPLE to get an element

if (box1.parentNode && box1.parentNode.contains(box1)) {
  box1.parentNode.removeChild(box1);
}

// Example: won't trigger an error:
if (box1.parentNode && box1.parentNode.contains(box1)) {
  box1.parentNode.removeChild(box1);
}

// Example: would trigger an error:
box1.parentNode.removeChild(box1);
```

```html
<div id="box1">a</div>
<div id="box2">b</div>
<div id="box3">c</div>
```

Comment: What happens if `box1` is `null`?

Comment: it can't be null, we set it to hold an element. But it might not have an parentElement in the DOM when it's not in the dom (anymore), thats why it checks for parentNode but not for box1 itself

Comment: I meant if `box1` element was not in DOM, wouldn't `document.getElementById("box1")` return null?

Comment: :D I saw your answer, and be assured I did not downvote it. But `document.getElementById("box1")` is just an example  to get an Element

Comment: No worries.  I was trying to check whether you should be using `box1 && box1.parentNode...`

Comment: Well I thought about that when writing the code, but I think its obsolete since if you are using a var you should know what it is